# GCP billing export dataset - resource level query

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing

billing detailed export going to bigquery. Able to run a lot of label centric queries.

**All resources within a given environment label**
All resources are labeled with the environment label. I am able to get the aggregation for a given label - e.g. environment = development.

However, what I am not able to figure out is getting a list of all the resources with the label. As an added bonus, I would like to get all the resources with a label (e.g. environment) and a given type (e.g. type = compute)

### **resource cost grouped by environment**

#standardSQL
SELECT   (SELECT value from UNNEST(project.labels) where key = "environment") env,
ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) as charges,
ROUND(SUM((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM UNNEST(credits))),2) as credits FROM
myproject.mygcp_billing_export_dataset
GROUP BY env

Comment: Hi user2736158, Does this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples) help you for billing export dataset resource level queries ?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your query is filtering for `project.labels`. Labels can be set on any resource, even a GCP project is considered as a resource.

You can [group by a label map](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/standard-usage#group_by_label_map_as_a_json_string) this to see all the labels and their respective cost. Inorder for you to get resource-level cost breakdown, there are two options:

- Setup **detailed data export** and [view resource-level costs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/detailed-usage#resource-level-costs-on-invoice)
- **Add a unique label** to every resource (we recommend setting a label like the instance_id, or resource_id that's unique for every resource so that you can drilldown for an individual resource)

Once you do this, you can to get your GCP cost on a resource-level granularity by:

- Running SQL queries on the BigQuery tables to aggregate and filter on months
- Use a cloud cost management platform to drill down on any granularity

Screenshot of [Unit Costs](https://www.economize.cloud/capabilities/unit-costs) in Economize (disclaimer: I run [Economize](https://www.economize.cloud/), a cloud cost optimization platform built for GCP/AWS).

[image: GCP resource cost]

Comment: already done all of that - otherwise my previous query would not be working. please read the question before answering.